# How to change the density of x-tick in Matplotlib chart?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I plot a chart with matplotlib but the x-ticks are too crowded. May I know any solution to fix it?

```
from pandas_datareader import data
import datetime

tickers = 'AAPL'

dateToday = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")#年月日20190526

# Only get the adjusted close.
tickers_data = data.DataReader(tickers,
                       start='', 
                       end=dateToday, 
                       data_source='yahoo')[["Adj Close", "Volume"]][-250:]

returns = tickers_data.pct_change()

plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))

ax = sns.barplot(x=returns.index.strftime('%d/%-m'), y=returns['Adj Close'], color='#73a9d1')

plt.xticks(rotation = 90)
plt.title('Returns' + '\n' + tickers)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Try `plt.bar(returns.index, returns['Adj Close'])`?

Comment: Hello. Is there has solution for matplotlib?

Comment: That is the solution for matplotlib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see, for example, every fifth x-tick (x-tick step is 5), you can improve your code in this way:

```
step = 5
x_values = returns.index.strftime('%d/%-m')
x_ticks_values = x_values[::step]

plt.figure(figsize = (12, 6))

ax = sns.barplot(x = x_values, 
                 y = returns['Adj Close'], 
                 color = '#73a9d1')

plt.xticks(ticks = np.arange(0, (len(x_values) + step), step), 
           labels = x_ticks_values,
           rotation = 90)
```

[image: Final Plot]